# How do I call a PHP function in all the pages?

Tags: 7, hooks, performance, caching

I used the Boost module for performance issues, and it creates _.html files every time it serves a file from the cache. I need to write a PHP function it should call every page, even the cached ones. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I may be wrong here, but if you wanted to call a PHP function on every page, you would put it in `hook_boot`. I am not sure if that still applies if Boost is loading an HTML file, but I think it happens early enough where it would. Especially if your custom module has a higher weight than Boost.

Comment: it is not working. i already tried that.

Comment: It's not possible. Apache serves the page and PHP is bypassed. You can use a javascript to run the PHP. Boost 6.x has an example: [boost_stats_generate](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/boost/tree/boost.module?h=6.x-1.x#n2462), http://cgit.drupalcode.org/boost/tree/stats/boost_stats.php?h=6.x-1.x

Comment: where i need to put php code.